# Is it possible to do math inside of a variable name? For example: S[BP1P - 8]O == false

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that outputs all possible moves(chess). I started by creating variables to check if the spaces are occupied or not so S0O, S1O, etc. Now I want to take a piece marked by a variable in this case BP1(Black pawn 1) with an int value marking square. So if BP1 = 48 how would I check if S40O is empty. This goes for any value of BP1.

Edit: I have been getting suggestions to use a `std::unordered_map`. So now that I have looked into these I do not quite see how this would let me check a certain entry based on an input.

Comment: I would suggest that rather than using variable names directly, have something like an `std::unordered_map<std::string, bool>` where you map strings to bools. In general if you find yourself with 64 variables with extremely programmatically generated names, you'll usually want to have some kind of container rather than actual variables named "S0O" and so on.

Comment: No.   C++ does not allow creating a variable name in that way.

Comment: @NathanPierson is it possible you could give an example of one? Or a place where i could go to learn how to use one.

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) has a good reference page on the data structure with some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the example from the link above, I put together some code that demonstrates how to use the unordered_map and manipulate the strings within, or you can change the keys before they're assigned (the keys are the colors "RED", "BLUE", and "GREEN" in this example).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    // Create an unordered_map of three strings (that map to strings)
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> u = {
        {"RED","#FF0000"},
        {"GREEN","#00FF00"},
        {"BLUE","#0000FF"}
    };

    u["RED"][3] = '2';

    // Just a random string manipulation
    for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < u["BLUE"].length(); i++)
        u["BLUE"][i] = i + 'a';

    std::cout << u["RED"] << std::endl;
    std::cout << u["BLUE"] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helps so much.

Comment: One question here, So now that I have this map how would this let me choose a specific entry based on an input value

Comment: Each key can be named based on the input value being entered. For example (using the above code) if I want to get the value when the user inputs "RED" I would write u[user_input] -- which will return the value "#FF0000" -- assuming we have a variable, std::string user_input = "RED". Take note, that once a key is created it cannot be changed, only removed. But because the keys are string based they can be customized at runtime.

Comment: Thank you so much this makes sense

Comment: Also, because I think you may run into this issue. To add a new key and value when the program is running, you would simply write this: `// Add two new entries to the unordered_map
   // Assuiming we have the variable std::string user_input = "#FFFFFF";
    u["BLACK"] = "#000000";
    u["WHITE"] = user_input;`